# Adding inline script to a joomla 3 index.php

Tags: php, joomla

I need to put this line into a Joomla `index.php`, I've tried different ways but they don´t work.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $("#header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Block of JavaScript code in Joomla can be declared using `JDocument` class `AddScriptDeclaration` method.

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
   $(window).load(function(){$("#header").sticky({topSpacing:0});}); 
');
?>
```